# Magento 2 REST API Add validation for data interface payload

Tags: magento2, rest-api, validation, save, post-data

I have created a custom REST API to save data into my table. My table contains many fields so I am using the DataInterface structure for payload.

Now I need to add a validation like as below

> {
> "message": ""%fieldName" is required. Enter and try again.",
> "parameters": {
> "fieldName": "firstname"
> }
> }

How can I do it?